# Python os.walk only finding system files

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to get os.walk to write the filepath of every file in the C drive to a text file in another drive and it is only finding a bunch of internal windows files that the normal windows user can't even see, e.g. C:ar-SA/fms.dll.mui, C:CatRoot/{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}/Containers-ApplicationGuard-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-GB~10.0.19041.1826.cat

```
logfile=open("Z:allfileslog.txt","w")
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk("C:"):
    for filename in files:
        logfile.write(os.path.join(dirname,filename)+'\n')
logfile.close()
```

I have noticed that while it doesn't appear to see, say, C:/Users, if I actually run it with os.walk("C:/Users"), it *will* recognise the files and subfolders therein. Furtherly, if I say

```
logfile=open("Z:allfileslog.txt","w")
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk("C:"):
    print(dirs)
    for filename in files:
        logfile.write(os.path.join(dirname,filename)+'\n')
logfile.close()
```

It *will* see the Users folder, somewhere within the mass of arrays that the `dirs` variable contains, however, I don't know how to take advantage of this to find the actual files I want. (Note that I *do* want these system files to be output to my text file, but I also want it to find normal files as well)

I don't think it is a problem with permissions in the C drive, because 1. The system files would be the last files my computer would let me look if it wanted to deny me permission and 2. I have been able to write to specific files, such as a text file I put into my downloads folder and directly gave the path to for the open() function.

Why isn't it seeing the other directories and files?

Comment: _Why isn't it seeing the other directories_ Because you're only iterating over `files`. 
 You're not iterating over `dirs`, which are the subdirectories.

Comment: What would the code with iterating over the subdirectories be (as in where would the for loop go, and what would be in it)?

Comment: @JohnGordon `os.walk` already goes over the directories.

Comment: What happened when you tried `os.walk("C:\\")`?

Comment: What happened with `followlinks=True`?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, but this code does not individually do anything with `dirname`.  That variable is only used in combination with each item in `files`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't think they're concerned with the directories themselves. Only with files. Their objective is about *"the filepath of every file"* and they write the file `allfileslog.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It's the old Windows "C:" versus "C:/" trap

When you say "C:" to windows, it interprets as the *currently selected* directory on the C drive. This happens to be some internal folder. We know that because it contains immediate children files of "ar-SA" (a language identifier for Saudi Arabian Arabic) and "CatRoot" (a folder normally found in "C:\Windows\System32").

Here is my own `C:\Windows\System32` as an example:

[image]

#### Starting from the root

To specifically mean the *root* of the C drive, you must add a slash. (Forward or backward slash, depending on where you are writing it).

Try this

```
logfile=open("Z:allfileslog.txt","w")
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/"):
    for filename in files:
        logfile.write(os.path.join(dirname,filename)+'\n')
logfile.close()
```

#### Preventing falling into this trap

When your last position on the Z: drive is already the correct folder, writing to "Z:allfileslog.txt" is successful.

However, if you really meant specifically the root of the Z drive, you should get into good habits by calling it this:

```
logfile=open("Z:/allfileslog.txt","w")
```

This will help you remember in other circumstances, such as with the C drive, where your current position was inside a User directory and not C:/

Comment: But how to explain that their second code, which also only used `"C:"`, apparently did come across the Users folder but didn't walk into it?